# Weird Positive Lookahead behaviour in java.util.regex engine

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I've text with many animals of certin kinds and some traps, and other text with no mean, e.g. "`cat dog house 131 bird 1341 house trap cat cat cat dog trap house dog house trap`".

I'm trying to build a regex that will find the nearest-precedence-animal to each traps, e.g. "cat dog house 131 **bird** 1341 house ***trap*** cat cat cat **dog** ***trap*** house **dog** house ***trap***".

I've wrote this regex: `(cat|dog|bird)(?!.*(cat|dog|bird).*).*trap`

and here is my full Java-code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(cat|dog|bird)(?!.*(cat|dog|bird).*).*trap");
Matcher m = p.matcher("cat dog house 131 bird 1341 house trap cat cat cat dog trap house dog house trap");
int start = 0;
while (m.find(start)) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    start = m.start + 1; //increment
}
```

Wierdly it finds only the last occuerence, and not the first, the second and the last. the output of the above code is:

```
dog house trap
dog
```

Why is that? I've tried to anchor it to the start with prepending `^.*?` to the regex, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(cat|dog|bird)((?!cat|dog|bird).)*?trap");
Matcher m = p.matcher("cat dog house 131 bird 1341 house trap cat cat cat dog trap house dog house trap");
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1) + " :: " + m.group(0));
}
```

which produces:

```
bird :: bird 1341 house trap 
dog :: dog trap 
dog :: dog house trap
```

A brief explanation:

```
(cat|dog|bird)        # match one of: 'cat', 'dog' or 'bird'
(                     # start group 2
  (?!cat|dog|bird).   #  if none of 'cat', 'dog' or 'bird' are ahead, match any char (except line breaks)
)*?                   # end group 2 and reluctantly match it zero or more times
trap                  # match 'trap'
```

You *could* add `trap` in the negative look-ahead, but the "reluctant" quantifier will cause the first occurrence of `trap` to be matched as the end.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your expression says that the animal can not be followed by *any animal* ever. That's why only the last "trapped animal" is matched.

It's a tricky problem to solve, since basically you want to say "*with something in between that **does not match** `bird|dog|cat`*".

The best solution I can come up with is this (and it ain't pretty!)

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String pat = "(cat|dog|bird)([^bcd]|b(?!ird)|c(?!at)|d(?!og))*trap";

        String str = "cat dog house 131 bird 1341 house trap cat cat cat dog " +
                     "trap house dog house trap";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pat);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        int start = 0;
        while (m.find(start)) {
            System.out.printf("Found trapped %s at %d%n", m.group(1), m.start());
            start = m.start() + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Found trapped bird at 18
Found trapped dog at 51
Found trapped dog at 66
```

Basically it says,

- `cat|dog|bird`, followed by
- anything character except `b`, `c` and `d`, or

  - `b` (but not followed by `ird`), or
  - `c` (but not followed by `at`), or
  - `d` (but not followed by `og`).
- followed by `trap`

Answer (score 0):

I can't edit, but in the last line it should be `start = m.start + 1;`.

Answer (score 0):

As aioobe states this is messy to solve and will only get messier to solve by means of RegEx as your requirements become more complex.

How about something along the lines of (pseudocode)...

```
str = "cat dog house 131 bird 1341 house trap cat cat cat dog trap house dog house trap";
arr = str.split(" "); //split on spaces
trapping = null;

for each item in arr {
  if (isTrap(item) && trapping != null) { 
    reportTrappedAnimal(trapping);
    trapping = null;     
  } else if (isAnimal(item)) { 
    trapping = item;
  }
}
```

You could use regex to implement `isAnimal()` and `isTrap()` but that would probably be overkill or impractical depending on your requirement.